# I logged in with facebook. Can I merge that account with my regular OpenID account?

Tags: support, openid, facebook

I have an account at stackoverflow.com with some reputation. Out of curiosity I logged in with Facebook and it created a new account with rep 1.

[image]

Now I added the OpenID of my real account to the new account because I thought that would either fail or merge the two accounts. What happens is that I'm redirected at a page that looks like this:

[image]

It seems I'm logged in with my old OpenID account now but still viewing the new accounts 
profile. The accounts have not been merged apparently.

What is expected to happen if a user with an existing account logs in with Facebook (and maybe acquires some reputation)? I think some users will expect both accounts to be separate, others might expect an easy way to merge their accounts.

Is there a way to merge both accounts?

*I don't need my accounts to be merged in particular, I just find the current behaviour confusing and wanted to know if a merge is possible.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accounts can be merged by moderators.

Flag a post from one of the accounts for moderator attention linking to the other account. They'll e-mail you and ask you to edit the profiles to indicate a) that you own both accounts (if it's not obvious) and b) which you want to keep.

You can then set up the alternate login to Facebook (or OpenID depending on which account you keep).

Asking here is also a way of attracting moderator attention.

Comment: So you are saying that there is only a manual merge requested by email. I wonder if that happens really that rarely that it's not a pain for the mods?

Comment: @Ludwig - Merging accounts is an irreversible action so it's right that it should be manually initiated. I don't know how often it happens on SO so I can't say whether it's a pain or not.